# php menu navigation include

Tags: php, menu, navigation

I'm working on my homepage and in my layout have an included navigation.php. I 
 Basically, the code in the layout is

```
DIV <?php include ('header.php'); ?>
DIV <?php include ('navigation.php'); ?>
DIV <?php
  if(is_null($GET["page"])) {
    $page = "home";
  }else{
    $page = $GET["page"];
  }
   include(''.$page.'.php');
?>
```

The code in navigation.php is

```
<ul>
<li><a href='index.php?page="home"'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?page="explore"'><span>Explore</span></a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?page="contact"'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Still, when clicking the links, home keeps being included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy!

in the list tags you have a bonus apostrophe.. they aren't neccesary.

in html languagae the link tag `<a href="src/file.html">click me</a>`

if you want to use php get-method, you can code just simple:

```
<a href="?page=contact">Im the contact link</a>
```

etc.

I hope i could help

btw:
with my prevous link-format I give you a working example-code (I think, it's better, and secure)
Hy!

a working example:

```
<?php  
if(!empty($_GET['page']))  
{  
if (!file_exists($_GET['page'].".php") )  
{  
include("home.php");  
}  
else  
{  
include($_GET['page'] .".php");  
}  
}  
else  
{  
include("home.php");  
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to both really quick answers! I just tried the second method - now it works perfectly - as is.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question: the PHP superglobal for url parameters is **$_GET**, not **$GET**.

The correct code would be:

```
DIV <?php include ('header.php'); ?>
DIV <?php include ('navigation.php'); ?>
DIV <?php
  if (!isset($_GET["page"]) || $_GET["page"] == "home") {
    $page = "home";
  } else if ($_GET["page"] == "explore") {
    $page = "explore";
  } else if ($_GET["page"] == "contact") {
    $page = "contact";
  } else {
    $page = "error";
  }

  include($page . '.php');
?>
```

You should be getting notices for an undefined variable, which will help you debug stuff like this. Check your [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings to make sure you output notices during development, or look in your logs.

Secondly, never, ever, allow user input to go directly into your program without sanitization. The example above will leave you open to a [File Inclusion Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability#PHP). Instead, use user input to check for a certain value, and manually assign the include value if you want to do something like in your code example.